# Wait for function before executing other in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

```
async function getDetails() {
        var raw = JSON.stringify({
            "deliveryBoyName": userName,
        });

        const requestOptions = {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            body: raw
        };

        const result = await fetch(apiLink1, requestOptions);
        const jsonResult = await result.json();
        const routedetails = jsonResult.routedetails;

        if (currDetails.length === 0) {
            const promises = routedetails.map(element => {
                const raw1 = JSON.stringify({
                    "deliveryBoyName": "mikey",
                    "deliveryDate": "04-07-2023",
                    "orderPriority": (element.orderPriority + 30).toString()
                });

                const requestOptions1 = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
                    body: raw1
                };

                return fetch(apiLink2, requestOptions1)
                    .then(result => result.json())
                    .then(result => {
                        result = result.routedetails;
                        return result;
                    });
            });

            return Promise.all(promises)
                .then(results => {
                    setCurrDetails([...currDetails, ...results]);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });


        }

    }


    async function setCurrentIndex() {
        setDeliveryNumber(currDetails[0][0].orderPriority);
        for (let i = 0; i < currDetails.length; i++) {
            if (currDetails[i][0].messagedates.length === 0) {
                setIndex(i);
                setDeliveryNumber(currDetails[i][0].orderPriority);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    async function setDetails() {
        await getDetails();
        await setCurrentIndex();
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        setDetails();
    }, []);
```

In the above code actually **getDetails()** and **setCurrentIndex()** are main functions that need to be executed to update the data. In **getDetails()** function the state currDetails gets updated which I need to use in **setCurrentIndex()** function. With the help of async, await I expect that flow will be as such

getDetails() -> setCurrentIndex()

But it is not happening so, and I got **Promise rejection** warning. I have been trying this from really long time.

Thank you in advance for the solution.

Note : apiLink1, apiLink2 are not original api links

Answer (score 0):

It's really hard to tell exactly what your problem is because I can't see all your code. My guess is though when you use async/await in react with setState hooks the state value wont be set immediately. In fact React really doesn't update the state until the next render.

Example:

```
const [details, setDetails = useState('hasDetails');

useEffect(() => {
getDetails()
},[])

const getDetails = async () => {
setDetails('CoolDetails')
console.log('DetailsValue:', details) //Prints "DetailsValue: hasDetails"
}
```

One solution that might work for you is using the setter function documented in react documentation: https://react.dev/reference/react/useState#updating-state-based-on-the-previous-state

Example:

```
const [details, setDetails = useState('hasDetails');

useEffect(() => {
getDetails()
},[])

const getDetails = async () => {
setDetails('CoolDetails');

setDetails(pendingState => pendingState + 'AreCool');

}
```

Hopefully I am guessing right here but if not let me know maybe I can help you further with more information.